# SQLAlchemy rollback

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Почему ORM не может сама откатить транзакцию в случае ошибки? А заставляет меня покрывать работу с БД в подобную штуку.

```
@contextmanager
def on_session():
    # db.session.begin(subtransactions=True)
    try:
        yield
        db.session.commit()
    except:
        db.session.rollback()
        raise
```

Уточняю. Вот у нас есть вот такой код

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
# Python 3.8.5 x64
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from settings import settings

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = settings.FLASK_SECRET_KEY
app.config.from_object(settings)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)


db.create_all()

try:
    print("1")
    db.session.add(User(id=1))
    db.session.commit()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"{type(e).__name__}{getattr(e, 'args', None)}")

try:
    print("2")
    db.session.add(User(id=1))
    db.session.commit()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"{type(e).__name__}{getattr(e, 'args', None)}")

try:
    print("One")
    db.session.execute("insert into user (id) values (1);")
    db.session.commit()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"{type(e).__name__}{getattr(e, 'args', None)}")

try:
    print("Two")
    db.session.execute("insert into user (id) values (1);")
    db.session.commit()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"{type(e).__name__}{getattr(e, 'args', None)}")

try:
    print("Three")
    db.session.execute("insert into user (id) values (2);")
    db.session.commit()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"{type(e).__name__}{getattr(e, 'args', None)}")
```

В ответ мы получим вот так

```
1
2
IntegrityError('(sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: user.id',)
One
PendingRollbackError("This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: user.id\n[SQL: INSERT INTO user (id) VALUES (?)]\n[parameters: (1,)]\n(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)",)
Two
PendingRollbackError("This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: user.id\n[SQL: INSERT INTO user (id) VALUES (?)]\n[parameters: (1,)]\n(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)",)
Three
PendingRollbackError("This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: user.id\n[SQL: INSERT INTO user (id) VALUES (?)]\n[parameters: (1,)]\n(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)",)
```

Получается следующее. Первая операция выполняется успешно, вторая операция валится, по понятной причине. А все остальные валятся потому что мне теперь нужно сделать db.session.rollback().

С другой стороны если сделать вот так

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
# Python 3.8.5 x64
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from settings import settings

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = settings.FLASK_SECRET_KEY
app.config.from_object(settings)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)


db.create_all()

try:
    print("One")
    db.session.execute("insert into user (id) values (1);")
    db.session.commit()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"{type(e).__name__}{getattr(e, 'args', None)}")

try:
    print("Two")
    db.session.execute("insert into user (id) values (1);")
    db.session.commit()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"{type(e).__name__}{getattr(e, 'args', None)}")

try:
    print("Three")
    db.session.execute("insert into user (id) values (2);")
    db.session.commit()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"{type(e).__name__}{getattr(e, 'args', None)}")
```

Вот в этом случае результат будет таким

```
One
Two
IntegrityError('(sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: user.id',)
Three
```

О чудо. Хоть второй запрос и был зафейлин, это не помешало третьему выполниться успешно. Вопрос, почему так? Я хочу чтобы в первом случае все работало также как и во втором. Чтобы запросы не мешали друг другу. А так получается что, я при использовании моделей, могу легко получить полу рабочее приложение, которое не еще не упало, но с базой работать уже не будет.

Comment: Она сама откатывает транзакцию в базе в случае ошибки. Вызов `.rollback()` не приводит к откату, как можно было бы подумать, а переводит состояние сессии из неактивного в активное, делая ее снова доступной для использования. То бишь это сброс логического состояния сессии после ошибки.

Comment: окей. вопрос не поменялся. ORM сама свое состояние не может контролировать? зачем на меня это возлагать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос содержится в официальной документации: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/faq/sessions.html#but-why-isn-t-the-one-automatic-call-to-rollback-enough-why-must-i-rollback-again

Если я правильно его понял, то это сделано, чтобы вам сложнее было себя запутать. Вы уже [неявно открыли](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_basics.html#auto-begin) транзакцию, когда вызвали `session.add()`.
Затем вы явно решили ее применить вызовом `session.commit()`. Но произошла ошибка, поэтому вам следует так же явно ее откатить при помощи `session.rollback()`. Это просто странно, что вы хотите явно закрывать хорошую транзакцию, а плохую -- нет.

Транзакция, с которой вы работаете при помощи `session`, называется логической. На самом деле это обертка над реальной транзакцией в базе данных, для которой SQL-оператор `ROLLBACK` вызывается неявно, когда возникает исключение. Вам уже написали об этом в комментарии: даже если вы не напишете `session.rollback()`, откат реальной транзакции все равно произойдет (но не произойдет сброса состояния логической транзакции). Исключение выбрасывает `session.flush()`, который вставляет операции в реальную транзакцию, когда вы вызываете `session.commit()`.

Если вы не хотите явно закрывать логическую транзакцию, то можете написать так:

```
try:
    with db.session.begin():
        db.session.add(new_row)
except sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError as error:
    print(type(error))
    print(error)
```

Здесь методы commit и rollback будет вызывать за вас менеджер контекста.

Comment: тупость. если я неявно открыл транзакцию. то я также неявно хочу ее закрыть. независимо от того хорошая она или плохая. то что от меня требуется вызывать commit тоже идиотизм.

Answer (score -1):

Ну если у Вас 1 запись и ошибка в ней, то записи не будет. А если у Вас несколько записей, то по правилам хорошего тона, сначала надо сделать временную запись через `session.flush()`

После того как все временные записи прошли успешно - надо записать в БД через `session.commit()` и откатить в случае ошибки `session.rollback()` и потом закрыть сессию через `session.close()`.

**Если не делать откат, то у Вас может получиться не целостная БД**

Таким образом правильно делать так:

```
try:
    ...
    db.session.flush()
    .......
    db.session.commit()
except:
    ....
    db.session.rollback()
finally:
    db.session.close()
```

Дополнение:

1. При `.flush()` - изменения не сохраняются постоянно на видимом диске других транзакций, пока база данных не получает COMMIT для текущей транзакции. Подробнее: [Разница .flush() и .commit()](https://www.rupython.com/sqlalchemy-flush-commit-3055.html)
2. Метод `rollback()` используется для отмены последних изменений, внесенных в базу данных. Если возникает условие, при котором пользователь не удовлетворен изменениями, внесенными в базу данных, или транзакция базы данных терпит неудачу, можно использовать метод `rollback()` для получения исходных данных, которые были изменены с помощью метода `commit()`. Подробнее: [Операция фиксации и отката в Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/commit-rollback-operation-in-python/)
3. В Вашем дополненном коде - В 1ой части уже завалилась сессия после 2го коммита и Вы пытаетесь через `.execute()` провести запрос, который естественно уже не будет работать. А во 2ой части Вы сразу начали делать через `.execute()`, который начинает на рабочей сессии и вернет ее в рабочее состояние, если завалит ее.

Comment: вот я и спрашиваю. почему алхимия возлагает на меня все это? а не делает все это сама когда я вызываю `db.session.execute(state)`

Comment: более того commit всегда вызывает flush. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#committing это алхимия делает, а откат транзакции в случае ошибки не делает) че за бред

Comment: @alex,  **session.flush()** - еще в БД не помещено,  а **session.commit()** - уже помещено.

Comment: да блин. но я ведь не об этом спрашиваю.

Comment: у меня суть вопроса не "как", а "почему"

Comment: @alex ,внес дополнения к ответу.